# How to map a source onto another?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have two case classes

```
case class Color (name: String, shades: List[Shade] = List.empty)

case class Shade (shadeName: String)
```

I also have parsers for both:

```
object ColorParser {
    def apply(
    s: String): Either[List[SomethingElse], Color] = {
        val values = s.split("\\|", -1).map(_.trim).toList
        validateColor(values).leftMap(xs => xs.toList).toEither
    }
}

object ShadesParser {
    def apply(s: String)
    : Either[List[SomethingElse], Shade] = {
        val values = s.split('|').map(_.trim).toList
        validateShade(values).leftMap(xs => xs.toList).toEither
    }
}
```

I have a source for `Color` and a source for `Shade`.

```
  sourceForShade
  .via (framing("\n"))
  .map (_.utf8string)
  .map (_.trim)
  .map {
    s => ShadesParser(s)
  }
  .collect {
    case Right(shade) => shade
  }

  sourceForColor
  .via(framing("\n"))
  .map(_.utf8String)
  .map(_.trim)
  .map(s => ColorParser(s))
  .collect {
    case Right(color) => color
  }
  .map {color =>
       //Here I want access to Color object that has the property shades list property set based on sourceForShade. 
       //At the moment it only has the name field but the List[Shade] property is empty.
  }
```

**Question**

In the comments section for the `map`, how can I get access to a color object that also has `shades: List[Shade]` property populated based on `sourceForShade`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to first obtain a `Future[Seq[Shade]]` from the first stream, then apply the result of that `Future` to the second stream:

```
val shades: Future[Seq[Shade]] =
  sourceForShade
    .via(framing("\n"))
    .map(_.utf8String.trim)
    .map(ShadesParser)
    .collect {
      case Right(shade) => shade
    }
    .runWith(Sink.seq[Shade])

val colors: Future[Source[Color, _]] =
  shades map { s =>
    sourceForColor
      .via(framing("\n"))
      .map(_.utf8String.trim)
      .map(ColorParser)
      .collect {
        case Right(color) => color
      }
      .map(c => c.copy(shades = s.toList))
  }

val colorsWithShades: Source[Color, _] =
  Source.fromFuture(colors).flatMapConcat(identity)
```

Comment: What if I had a separate class `case class ColorShade(color: Color, shades: List[Shade])`

Comment: I asked a separate question for this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53796511/how-to-process-future-stream-to-create-an-instance-of-class-with-list-property Thank you for your help.