# How to process future stream to create an instance of class with list property

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a method that is takes in a future as parameter and also has a future inside it. I want to create a list from this method such that it takes values from the future that is passed in.

**Case Classes**

```
case class Color (colorName: String)
case class Shade (shadeName: String)
case class ColoShade (color: Color, shades: List[Shade])
```

**Methods**

```
val shadesFuture: Future[Seq[Shade]] = {
    val larSource: Future[Seq[LoanApplicationRegister]] =
      getMySource(ctx, id)
        .map(_.utf8String)
        .map(_.trim)
        .map(s => ShadeParser(s))
        .collect {
          case Right(shade) => shade
        }
        .runWith(Sink.seq)
}

//call the method
myMethod(shadesFuture)

//method definition
def myMethod(shadesFuture: Future[Seq][Shade]])
  :Future[ColorShade] {
    colorFuture
      .map(_.utf8String)
      .map(_.trim)
      .map { s =>
        ColorParser(s)
      }
      .collect {
        case Right(c) => c
      }
      .map { c =>  
         //How can I make an instance of ColorSade here? 
         //I tried 
         val colorShade = ColorShade(c, shadesFuture) 
         //but this doesn't work  

         //I would like to change this to instead be someOtherMethod(colorShade.c)
         someOtherMethod(c) 
      }
}
```

**Question**

How can I correctly return `ColorShade` from `myMethod` such that the `shades` property is the output from the passed in parameter `shadesFuture`?

Comment: You should be returning `Future[ColorShade]`

Comment: Yes, that what I meant to return. I have corrected it. now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you mean ... But I think you are looking for something like this:

```
 def myMethod(shadesFuture: Future[Seq[Shade]]) : Future[ColorShade] = for {
   shades <- shadesFuture
   color <- colorFuture.map(...) // whatever the transformations you wanted
   transformedColor = ColorParser(color.utf8String.trim) // or you can do them like this

   colorShade = ColorShade(color, shades)
   // whatever you wanted to do with it here
   _ = someOtherMethod(colorShade.c, colorShade.shades)
 } yield colorShade // or whatever you need to return. The result of this is `Future[ColorShade]`
```

This is called "for-comprehension" and is syntactic sure for a bunch of nested `.flatMap` calls. You could also writer it explicitly (this is not exactly what for-comprehension is desugared into, but functionally equivalent):

```
 shadesFuture
    .flatMap { shades => 
       colorFuture
         .map(...)  // transform, whatever
         .map(ColorShade(_, shades)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but this won't solve the flow I'm looking for. I am really looking for a way to change `someOtherMethod(c)` to `someOtherMethod(colorShade.c, colorShade.shades)`

Comment: In my question, I have access only to `c` not `ColorShade`

Comment: Yes. But in mine you have both :)

Comment: Thanks. Trying to wrap my little head around scala :)

Comment: Asked another question related to this but more about maps