# Transforming a map with an outer map

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to add an outer map to an existing map but still return the same thing from the method.

Here is how the existing map looks:

```
def someMethod(checkType: String) : Flow[ByteString, MyClass[OtherClass], NotUsed] = {
  someFlow
  .map (s => SomeParser(s))
  .collect {
    case Right(ts) => ts
  }
  .map {t =>
    val somedata = checkType match {
      case "foo" => SomeClass.someMethod(t)
    }
    (one, two)
  }
  .map {x =>
    x._2.leftMap(xs => {
      someMethod(x._1, xs.toList)
    }).toEither
  }
}
```

I am trying to add an outer map but still be able to return the same things that were being returned from the original map in the above method. I have tried below but doing this scala complains about the return mismatch. For ease of identification, I have commented which lines below are different.

```
def someMethod(checkType: String) : Flow[ByteString, MyClass[OtherClass], NotUsed] = {
  anotherFlow.map {l => //new
    someFlow 
    .map (s => SomeParser(s))
    .collect {
      case Right(ts) => ts
    }
    .map {t =>
      val myClass = MyCaseClass(t, l) //new
      val somedata = checkType match {
        case "foo" => SomeClass.someMethod(myClass.t) //modified
      }
      (one, two)
    }
    .map {x =>
      x._2.leftMap(xs => {
        someMethod(x._1, xs.toList)
      }).toEither
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The cyclomatic complexity of the second snippet is its first problem. It's not super readable, so harder to reason about. And that seems to be a simplified version, so it's probably even more difficult to read in your real code. Besides that, what's the type of `anotherFlow`? What's the type of `ts`?

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do this? I'm trying to do something similar to explained in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53794892/how-to-map-a-source-onto-another the type for `anotherFlow` is `Future[Seq[T]]` the type for `ts` is `Color`